# Prove that $V=\text{Ker}(T) \bigoplus \text{Image}(T^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let be $V$ and $W$ vector spaces of finit dimension over $\mathbb{C}$ with inner product $\left \langle    ,  \right \rangle_{v}$ and $\left \langle , \right \rangle_{w}$ respectively. Consider $T:V \rightarrow W$ a surjective linear transformation such that exists $T^{*}:W \rightarrow V$ and $\left \langle Tv,w \right \rangle_{w}=\left \langle v,T^{*}w \right \rangle_{v}$,  $\forall v\in V$ and $w \in W$

1. Prove that $T^{*}$ is injective
2. Prove that $\text{Ker}(T)$ and $\text{image}(T^*)$ are orthogonal
3. Prove that $V=\text{Ker}(T) \bigoplus \text{Image}(T^*)$

I've already proved (1) and I have a doubt in (2) and (3). My doubts are:

- On (2) I did this: (Can I conclude in this way that the inner product is zero?)

Let be $v\in \text{Ker}(T)$ and $T^{*}w\in \text{Image}(T^{*})$

$\left \langle v,T^{*}w \right \rangle_{v}=\left \langle Tv,w \right \rangle_{w}=\left \langle 0,w \right \rangle_{w}=0$

Therefore, $\text{Ker}(T)$ and $\text{Image}(T^{*})$ are orthogonal.

> How can I prove (3)?

Comment: I posted an answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer.

Comment: Hi @Ramiro! Sorry for the delay, your answer is very clear, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof for item 2 is correct.

For item 3, note that
$V=\text{Image}(T^*)^\perp \bigoplus \text{Image}(T^*)$ and, from item 2, we already know that
$\text{Ker}(T) \subseteq \text{Image}(T^*)^\perp$. So, all we need to prove is that $\text{Image}(T^*)^\perp \subseteq  \text{Ker}(T) $.

Suppose $v\in \text{Image}(T^*)^\perp$, then, for all $w \in W$,
$$ \left \langle v,T^{*}w \right \rangle_{V} =0 $$
which means, for all $w \in W$,
$$ \left \langle Tv,w \right \rangle_{W} =0 $$
So $T v = 0$, which means $v \in  \text{Ker}(T) $.

So, we have proved $\text{Image}(T^*)^\perp \subseteq  \text{Ker}(T) $. So we have
$\text{Ker}(T) = \text{Image}(T^*)^\perp$ and we have $V=\text{Ker}(T) \bigoplus \text{Image}(T^*)$